# Image Library (IMGLIB) on Gumstix?

Tags: c++, signal-processing, bitbake, gumstix

I need to run [AprilTags](https://github.com/zafrullahsyed/apriltags.git) C++ algorithm on gumstix using DSP image library. Without DSP,  Algorithm is eating up 85% cpu with 4fps. I am trying to get TI Image Library [IMGLIB](http://www.ti.com/tool/sprc264) on Gumstix with Yocto Project. I could not find any resources or hints how to do it.

It would be great if I can get some inputs on how to proceed with getting imglib on gumstix using yocto project/open-embedded

Should I write a recipe with bitbake or is there any other way to get IMGLIB on Gumstix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bitbake the TI Image Library IMGLIB, and you should obtain
a library and modules DSPlink, CMem, etc which should be used to
communicate with the Gumstix DSP. In your application you link
to the library (e.g. specify its path in the makefile) and add
the include header (.h) in your application source code. That
is the theory anyway. I have bitbaked it and trying to use IMGLIB
now. Can report some progress. What OS/kernel you are using ?

Brahim